# Using AMPScript to create dynamic content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to use AMPScript to create/display dynamic content in Marketing Cloud?   Will AMPScript do this out of the box?

(I know there's a built-in way to set and define Dynamic Content, but I'm curious about whether this can just be done with AMPScript.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AMPScript to create and display dynamic content out of the box.   Here's the [**function reference**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#alphalist) and list of [**personalization strings**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/).

Comment: I would also recommend to look into that list of functions depending on what you are trying to achieve: http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since I can't comment yet on the outdated 2014 response from Adam Spriggs, here's the [current link to the AMPscript function reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm).

### [Personalization Strings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/personalizationStringsAMPscript.htm):

| Personalization String | Description |
| --- | --- |
| _CarrierID | Carrier ID associated with the contact, contained in the contact CarrierID field. |
| _Channel | Channel associated with the contact, contained in the contact Channel field. |
| _City | City associated with the contact, contained in the contact City field. |
| _ContactID | Contact ID associated with the contact, contained in the contact ContactID field. |
| _ContactKey | Contact key associated with the contact, contained in the contact ContactKey field. Used to send SMS messages in MobileConnect. |
| _CountryCode | Country code associated with the contact, contained in the contact CountryCode field. |
| _CreatedBy | The entity that created the contact, contained in the contact CreatedBy field. |
| _CreatedDate | The date on which the contact was created, contained in the contact CreatedDate field. |
| _FirstName | The contact first name, contained in the FirstName field. |
| _IsHonorDST | Indicates whether the contact's time zone honors Daylight Savings Time, contained in the contact IsHonorDST field. |
| _LastName | The contact last name, contained in the contact LastName field. |
| _MobileNumber | The contact mobile number, contained in the contact MobileNumber field. |
| _ModifiedBy | The last user to modify contact information, contained in the contact ModifiedBy field. |
| _ModifiedDate | The last time a process modified contact information, contained in the contact ModifiedDate field. |
| _Priority | The priority to use when sending a message to a contact, contained in the contact Priority field. |
| _Source | The source of contact information, contained in the contact Source field. |
| _SourceObjectID | The object ID of the source of contact information, contained in the contact SourceObjectID field. |
| _State | The state associated with a contact, contained in the contact State field. |
| _Status | The send status associated with a contact, contained in the contact Status field. |
| _UTCOffset | The time offset from UTC associated with a contact, contained in the contact UTCOffset field. |
| _ZipCode | The ZIP code associated with a contact, contained in the contact ZipCode field. |